# autoHeight with WindowScroller doesn't render full List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

when i use `autoHeight` parameter on `WindowScroller`'s child (`List`),
it doesn't render whole list of items (only few of them), but without `autoHeight` everything renders, but the rest of page is not scrolling.

Thank you, there is my code and screenshot:

```js
const bars = this.props.bars

    const rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style }) => {
     const bar = bars.get(index)

      return (
        <div key={key} style={style}>
          <BarListItem
            key={key}
            onClick={this.props.onBarClick}
            {...this.props}
            {...bar}
          />
        </div>
      )
    }

    return <WindowScroller>
        {({ height, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop }) => (
          <AutoSizer disableHeight>
            {({ width }) => (
              <List
                autoHeight
                onScroll={onChildScroll}
                ref="List"
                height={height}
                rowCount={bars.size}
                rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
                rowHeight={height/5.5}
                width={width}
                isScrolling={isScrolling}
                // onChildScroll={onChildScroll}
                scrollTop={scrollTop}
              />)}
          </AutoSizer>
        )}
    </WindowScroller>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk0jC.png)

Comment: Please provide a runnable repro.

Comment: i did a runnable repro on plnkr, and everything is working as expected, but i can't find what i'm missing in my project. I will try to find by myself for now

Comment: Cool! Good luck :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?